# Very simple Apache htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

What I want to do:

Redirect this:

http://example.com/9hyf4dx

... and this:

http://www.example.com/9hyf4dx

to:

http://example.com/special.php?var=9hyf4dx

Answer (score 0):

Try this (it uses a regular expression if the variable you posted is just an example):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)*$ special.php?var=$1
```

if you want you can also add a rule that all visits to your site will have to have the WWW:

```
#force WWW on main domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you but I get an absolute server path like: `http://example.com/absolute/server/path/example.com/special.php?var=9hyf4dx`

Comment: sorry, didn't understand your comment

Comment: I meant, using your rewrite, `http://example.com/9hyf4dx` goes to `http://example.com/absolute/server/path/example.com/special.php?var=9hyf4dx`

Comment: Sorry, my bad, its  the last part [R,L] that was wrong, just remove that part - i will also edit my answer